# Shopify Admin API: How To Get Correct Prices For Discounted Order?

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api

I am building an integration between Shopify and our ERP via the admin API using GraphQL. All is working well except when I try and get the exact prices for an order.

In the documentation **discountedTotalSet** should be '*The total line price after discounts are applied*' but I am finding it returns the full price - see examples below.

Can anyone give me guidance on how to get the API to show the same prices that are on the order? I need this to match exactly line by line. This is the query I am using for the order:

```
{
  node(id: "gid://shopify/Order/4866288156908") {
    id
    ...on Order {
      name
      lineItems (first: 50) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            quantity
            sku
            discountedTotalSet {
              shopMoney {
                currencyCode
                amount
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the result, note amount says 599.00 but that is not correct, see screenshot for the same order from the UI.

```
{
  "data": {
    "node": {
      "id": "gid://shopify/Order/4866288156908",
      "name": "AK-1003",
      "lineItems": {
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "gid://shopify/LineItem/12356850286828",
              "quantity": 1,
              "sku": "AK-A1081",
              "discountedTotalSet": {
                "shopMoney": {
                  "currencyCode": "AUD",
                  "amount": "599.0"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

[Shopify UI screenshot*emphasized text*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hhu7.png)

Answer (score 1):

`discountedTotalSet` gives you the amount after discounts applied to that particular line. In your example you're applying a discount to the whole order. There is no field, in the `lineItem` object that will give you the expected value for that line.

So you have to distribute the whole discount to each single line.
I had the exact same problem and I had to implement this solution in python, I hope it helps:

```
from decimal import Decimal


def split_discounts(money, n):
    quotient = Decimal(round(((money * Decimal(100)) // n) / Decimal(100), 2))
    remainder = int(money * 100 % n)
    q1 = Decimal(round(quotient + Decimal(0.01), 2))  # quotient + 0.01
    result = [q1] * remainder + [quotient] * (n - remainder)
    return result  # returns an array of discounted amounts


def retrieve_shop_money(obj):
    return Decimal(obj['shopMoney']['amount']) if obj and obj['shopMoney'] and obj['shopMoney']['amount'] else Decimal(
        0)  # this is just to retrieve the inner shopMoney field


def get_line_price(order_node):
    discount = retrieve_shop_money(order_node["cartDiscountAmountSet"])
    non_free_lines = len([1 for item in order_node["lineItems"]["edges"] if
                          retrieve_shop_money(item["node"]["discountedTotalSet"]) > 0])

    if non_free_lines > 0:
        discounts = split_discounts(discount, non_free_lines)
    else:
        discounts = 0 # this was an edge case for me, that you might not consider
    discounted = 0  
    for item in order_node["lineItems"]["edges"]:
        gross = retrieve_shop_money(item["node"]["originalTotalSet"])  # THIS IS THE VALUE WITHOUT DISCOUNTS
        net = retrieve_shop_money(item["node"]["discountedTotalSet"])
        if net > 0:  # exluding free gifts
            net = net - discounts[discounted]  # THIS IS THE VALUE YOU'RE LOOKING FOR
            discounted = discounted + 1
```

So first I retrieve if the whole order was free. This was an edge case that was giving me some issues. In that case I just know that 0 is the answer I want.

Otherwise with the method `split_discounts` I calculate each single disount to be applied to the lines. Discounts can be different because if you discount $1 out of 3 items is going to be `[0.33,0.33,0.34]`. So the result is an array. Then I just loop through the lines and apply the discount if `discountedTotalSet` is `>0`.

Thinking about it, you might also want to be sure that the discount is greater than the value of the line. But that is an edge case that I never encouted, but depends on the kind of discounts you have.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the advice. They don't make it easy do they but I will try this method.